# Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

I get the #1009 error while it visually works, can someone help me? Thanks in advance.
arrBellen is a Array on field-level.

```
private function bellenSpel(mv:MovieClip,x:Number):void{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyHandler);
    if(landschap.x == x){
        mv.visible = true;
        mv.mouseEnabled = true;
    }
    else{
        mv.visible = false;
        mv.mouseEnabled = false;
    }

    landschap.lblScore_onderwater.text.text = "Score: " + vogelTimer.currentCount;

    if(vogelTimer.currentCount % 300 == 0) {
        var bel:Bel = maakBellen();
        arrBellen.push(bel);
    }

    for(var i = 0;arrBellen.length - 1;i++){
        var bl:Bel = arrBellen[i];
        bl.y += 2; // output says error is here 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think either your array isn't pospulated with the objects you think it is, or they can't cast to type Bel.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
var bel:Bel = maakBellen();
```

do like:

```
var bel:Bel = new maakBellen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's my assumptions up front... A mgraph is right or maakBellen() is actually a function that returns an instance of Bel

you have an error in your loop condition you have:

```
for(var i = 0;arrBellen.length - 1;i++){
    var bl:Bel = arrBellen[i];
    bl.y += 2; // output says error is here 
}
```

you should have

```
for(var i = 0;i < arrBellen.length;i++){
    var bl:Bel = arrBellen[i];
    bl.y += 2; // output says error is here 
}
```

I'm a bit confused as to why this is causing a NPE rather than an OutOfRange type error.